# Remove extra space in string in C without using any pre-define functions

Tags: c, char, whitespace, c-strings, trim

I want to remove extra spaces in string in C without using any predefine function.
Here is my code:

but still after **XYZ** one extra space is printing.
Is there any better approach please share

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {
    char str[30] = "   abcdef   abc   xyz   ";
    int l = strlen(str),n=0;
    printf("(");                // added for clarity
    for(int i=0;i<l;i++)
    {
        if(str[i]==' ')
        {
            n++;
            if(i==0 || i==l-1)
            {
                continue;
            }
            else
            {
                if(n>1)
                {
                    continue;
                }
                else{
                    printf("%c",str[i]);
                }
            }
        }
        else{
            n=0;
            printf("%c",str[i]);
        }
    }
    printf(")\n");             // added for clarity
    return 0;
}
```

Program output is

```
(abcdef abc xyz )
```

Expected output is

```
(abcdef abc xyz)
```

Comment: What are "extra spaces"?

Comment: extra white-space `"   abcdef   abc   xyz   "`

Comment: Other that using a FSM, I would recommend you create an output string first and then print it. Printing it while parsing is asking for look-ahead trouble.

Comment: @satyamjha Nevertheless it is unclear what are "extra spaces". Do you need to output characters of a string except spaces? Show the expected output.

Comment: Expected output is `abcdef abc xyz`

Comment: I suggest you a) remove leading spaces, b) remove trailing spaces, c) remove unnecessary intermediate spaces.

Comment: you are doing extra work to make your code hard to read -- "i" and "l" look very much the same.  One character variable names are bad and not descriptive.  Using two that look the same is especially bad.  If I was code-reviewing this I would send it back without reading the rest.

Comment: Never use l as a variable name (ell). In some fonts it is very hard to distinguish l from I and 1. Don't add unnecessary confusion to the code.

Answer (score 3):

Your program always outputs a space each time when `n` is equal to `1` and `i` is not equal to `0` or `l-1`. So one trailing space (if there are at least two trailing spaces) will be always outputted.

Also numerous continue statements make your code too complicated.

And using the standard string function `strlen` is redundant.

Always try to write a more general code. That is you could write a separate function that could be called for any string to output it.

Here is a demonstration program.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void output_string( const char *s )
{
    int space = 0;

    for ( ; *s != '\0'; ++s )
    {
        if (*s != ' ')
        {
            if (space) putchar( ' ' );

            putchar( *s );

            space = s[1] == ' ';
        }
    }
}

int main( void )
{
    putchar( '(' );
    output_string( "   abcdef   abc   xyz   " );
    printf( ")\n" );
}
```

The program output is

```
(abcdef abc xyz)
```

The function can be more general if to include processing of tab character `'\t'`.

To do so it is enough to include header `<ctype.h>` and change this statement

```
space = s[1] == ' ';
```

to

```
space = isblank( ( unsigned char )s[1] );
```

As you can see the function has no continue statements. You should avoid using the continue statement if possible. In general using the continue statement makes programs less readable.

Comment: The `output_string()` is a nice [FSM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite-state_machine).

Answer (score 2):

The goal of your code is to do two things.

1. If there is more than one space between words print only one space.
2. If there are spaces at the start or the end remove all those spaces.

The logic of your program handles 1) fine.  It also hands spaces at the start fine.  However, it does not handle spaces at the end.  This is because you don't know at the start of a sequence of spaces if it is an ending sequence, so you print the space before you know it is the ending sequence.

The best way to solve this problem is to "pre-process"  That is look at the string before the loop and find the first non space character.  And look at the string and find the last non space character (started at the end and going backwards.)

Now you can process the characters from the starting location to that ending location using the algorithm you have shown and it will work.

Hat tip: @weather vane's comment, which says the same thing but does not explain as much as this answer.

Answer (score 1):

1. Use functions.
2. There is no ned of calling `strlen`
3. The type of `l` is wrong (should be `size_t`)

```
char *trimAndStrip(char *str, char ch)
{
    char *head = str, *tail = str;
    if(str)
    {
        while(*tail == ch) tail++;
        while(*tail)
        {
            if(*tail != ch) *head++ = *tail++;
            else 
            {
                *head++ = *tail++;
                 while(*tail == ch) tail++;
            }
        }
    
        if(head > str && *head == ch) head--;
        *head = 0;
    }
    return str;
}

int main(void)
{
    char str[] = "   abcdef   abc   xyz   ";
    char str1[] = "abcdefxyz";
    char str2[] = "       ";
    char str3[] = "";

    printf("\"%s\"\n", trimAndStrip(str, ' '));
    printf("\"%s\"\n", trimAndStrip(str1, ' '));
    printf("\"%s\"\n", trimAndStrip(str2, ' '));
    printf("\"%s\"\n", trimAndStrip(str3, ' '));
}
```